# Prove that every operator on an odd-dimensional real vector space has an eigenvalue using induction.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**Theorem**
Every operator on an odd-dimensional real vector space has an eigenvalue.

**Incomplete proof**

Suppose that $V$ is a real vector space with an odd dimension.

The result is obviously true if $\dim V=1$. 
So now we assume the dimension of $V$ is an odd number greater than $1$. 
Assume that the result is true for all real vector spaces with dimension equaling $\dim V-2$.

Now we need to prove that $T$ has an eigenvalue. If it does, our work is done. 
If not, there is a $"-D$ subspace $U\leqslant V$ that is invariant under $T$.

> **(Doubt)**
>   I am aware that every operator on a finite-dimensional vector space has an invariant subspace of dimension $1$ or $2$. So why not consider two subspaces $U$ and $W$ of dimension $1$ and $1$ respectively?
>   How are we sure that there will exist a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace?

After that proof is very much clear to me.

**NB**

Source:
Alexander, Sheldon, '*Linear algebra done right*', $2^{\text{nd}}$ edition chapter $5$, last section.

Answer (score 1):

Because if there's an invariant subspace of dimension $1$, any nonzero element of that subspace is an eigenvector and we've assumed $T$ doesn't have any eigenvectors.

Comment: Why can't same thing happen in two dimensional space?

Comment: Oh..i think i get it. If T has an eigenvalue (say è) then T-èI is not injective . And hence one dimensional invariant subspace .